# JavaHelp: load helpset from external jar file

Tags: jar, external, javahelp

I'm working with a standalone java program that uses the javahelp system for the help files.  The program has a bunch of built-in 'modules' that the user can select at runtime to perform various analysis on data.  I'm adding the ability to run plug-in modules that are placed into a plugins folder, so that other developers can create their own algorithms.

I started with just .class files in the plugins folder, along with the javahelp .hs file and supporting docs (.xml, .html, .map, etc).  I was able to read the .hs file from the plugins folder and merge with the main programs help system, no problem.

Then I bundled all the files together in a jar, because that's how we envision most developers distributing their plugins.  The .class files all still load and run, but now I'm not able to load the .hs file anymore.  The HelpSet class requires a URL with the location of the .hs file.  Do I tell it to look inside the jar file?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is having the same issue, my problem was the format of the path name I was using to access the helpset file from inside the jar file.  The format (from section 4.6.7 of the JavaHelp users guide found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-0913/819-0913.pdf)) is to form the URL as:

```
URL helpSetLoc = new URL("jar:file:" + File.separator + pluginList.get(i).getJarFile()+"!/"+pluginList.get(i).getHelpSetName());
```

My `getJarFile()` method returned the name of the jar file (including absolute path).  My `getHelpSetName` method returned the package name and helpset name **separated by a forward slash**, as in `myPlugin/pluginHelp.hs`.

My problem was that I was using File.separator between the package name and the helpset filename, which returned a backslash in windows.  I also tried a double-backslash, which did the same.  I had to use a forward slash, or else the HelpSet constructor was not able to find the file.